# time.mktime returns same value with different input

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have problem, with different inputs **time.mktime** function returns the same value. The only difference is day of the week, but still.

```
beginning_of_the_meeting = []

S = 'Mon 01:00-23:00\nTue 01:00-23:00\nWed 01:00-23:00\nThu 01:00-23:00\nFri 01:00-23:00\nSat 01:00-23:00\nSun 01:00-21:00'

for meeting in iter(S.splitlines()):
    beginning_of_the_meeting.append(time.strptime(meeting[0:9] + ":2010", '%a %H:%M:%Y'))

for index in range(len(beginning_of_the_meeting)):
    print(time.mktime((beginning_of_the_meeting[index])))
    print(beginning_of_the_meeting[index])
```

and the output of it is:

```
1262304000.0
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
1262304000.0
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
1262304000.0
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
1262304000.0
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
1262304000.0
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
1262304000.0
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
1262304000.0
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strptime()` doesn't guarantee you'd get a valid datetime, it just does its best parsing things.

As you're parsing a partial datetime (day-of-week and time-of-day), you get a degenerate datetime back – as you can see, the only thing changing in the struct is the wday, hour and min fields.

That combined with the fact that [`mktime()` doesn't use `wday`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) (at least on Linux, probably elsewhere too):

> The function ignores the values supplied by the caller in the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday` fields.

results in what you're seeing; always the same output, since the fields actually used by `mktime()` are not changing.